# Different layout for iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe

I have a rails app with content other websites need to access via iframe.
The content should have a different layout when shown on the websites (no menu bar etc.)
I made a new layout file called iframe.html.erb
How can I check, whether the page is called form an external iframe so the right layout file is used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know when you doing

```
<iframe src="www.google.pl"></iframe>
```

you have no control over layout or styles of page display in iframe unless you own the page and can make it look whatever you like.

EDITED

If you displaying your own site go like this:

```
<iframe src="/some_site_that_i_can_change_code_in?from=iframe"></iframe>
```

and then in  controller of some_site_that_i_can_change_code_in:

```
if params[:from] == "iframe"
  render :layout => "for_iframe"
else
  render :layout => "normal"
end
```

Comment: I do know, how to set up an iframe. My question was, how can I tell my rails app that the page was called from an iframe.

Comment: But I don't want to show my own site in an iframe when it is called directly.

Comment: if site that is in src="" isn't yours and you don't have access to it then you can't do you what you want, in example you can't display only TopNews section from http://digg.com/news. If site is yours then do like i said in edited part of answer

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there would be a way to to this, without the external sites having to pass a param.

Comment: FYI for other's seeing this answer - this solution will fail on a page redirect. Saving a form, going to another page, etc. You have to  make sure you transport the parameter around each page load.

Comment: @jakeisonline any way to relay that param in a dry fasion? Perhaps an application before_filter? A session?

Answer (score 5):

A good way to control the specific layout and content when serving an iframe is to register an "iframe" mimetype.

```
## config/initializers/mime_types.rb

Mime::Type.register 'text/html', "iframe"
```

Create a view that matches the controller action being served ie: `show.iframe.haml`.  Then, when a request comes in with `format: iframe` it'll render the iframe version.

That way you can control exactly what's in the iframe on other sites.  No need to get crazy in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this is with Javascript and then redirect, but it's kind of messy and not really a good idea. See this thread for more info: [Detecting if this is an iframe load or direct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495135/detecting-if-this-is-an-iframe-load-or-direct)