# Is there any other way to block an iframe other than 'x-frame-options' 'sameorigin'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, iframe, x-frame-options

I work for a company that has a rails app and generally we want to block most of our controller actions from being embedded in an iframe, however some of our clients are asking for certain pages to be embeddable in iframes.

Rails 4 sets 'x-frame-options' to 'sameorigin' by default so my solution was to delete the 'x-frame-options' header when the http referer matched the url given to us by the client. The reason I deleted the x-frame-options instead of setting it to 'allow-from [url]' is because 'allow-from' is not supported by some relatively

My boss doesn't think this is the most secure solution though because the x-frame-options isn't supported by some older browsers.

Is there some way of detecting if a controller action is being embedded in an iframe that I could detect using a built in rails method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript and see if the window matches the toplevel window

```
var inIframe = window !== window.top; // true if in iframe false otherwise
```

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to know if there is a way of doing this in the controller?

Comment: There is no way AFAIK to do this completely in the controller (server side) but perhaps something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495135/detecting-if-this-is-an-iframe-load-or-direct